# How to call a ofstream file type in a void function

Tags: c++

I want to be able to create a function which writes in a file, but I want more specifically to declare the `ofstream` file before and call the file in the argument of the function. This leads me to the following question: what is the type of the `ofstream` file?

I tried to do `cout<<file<<endl;` to see what is the type of a `ofstream` file.

Comment: What do you mean by `ofstream file`? The type of an `ofstream` is `ofstream`. You should probably take in an `ostream&` though.

Comment: Obviously the type of on ofstream file is `ofstream`. However it's clear that you are really asking how to pass an `ofstream` object to a function. The best way to do that is to declare the parameter that takes the ofstream as `ostream&`. The reference is necessary because ofstream objects cannot be copied, and the type is ostream not ofstream because this allows the function to be used with any other type of output stream (`cout` for example) should you wish to do so.

Comment: Q: what is the type of a ofstream file?  A: An ofstream is an ofstream.  Period.  It's a [stream](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/) representing the bytes in a "file".  The *type* of the file (.pdf, .txt, .png. etc. etc) is not relevant to the stream.  Look here for more details on the C++ basic I/O classes: https://cplusplus.com/reference/iolibrary/  You might also be interested in [std::filesystem::file_type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_type)

Comment: `cout<<typeid(file).name()<<endl;` ... after demangling it you'll find that the type of a `std::ofstream` is `std::ofstream`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to write to a stream inside a function:

```
void output_function(std::ostream& out)
{
    out << "Pizza on the ground!\n";
}
```

Example of writing to a file stream:

```
void output_file_function(std::ofstream& file_out)
{
    file_out << "Comfortably numb.\n";
}
```

Finally, example of writing to a file:

```
void write_to_file(const std::string& file_name)
{
    std::ofstream my_file(filename);
    my_file << "No more school!\n";
    my_file.flush(); // For good measure.
}
```

### Edit 1:

Here's an example program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    std::ofstream    example_file("Example.txt");
    output_function(example_file);
    output_file_function(example_file);
    example_file.flush();
    return 0;
}
```